# Why is "Find my ... " no longer updating my AirTag's position?

Tags: macos, find-my, airtag

I have an AirTag, a MacBook and a couple of iPhones in my family.

If I open the "Find my ..." app on my Mac, the AirTag's position is **no longer updated**. It is listed as "Last seen March 16 2022" (it is currently April 4th).

But when I open the "Find my ..." app on my iPhone, the AirTag's position **is** updated ("last updated 4 minutes ago").

My other devices' positions (the phones, the MacBook) are all correctly updated in both the Mac app and the iPhone app.

So the Mac "Find my ..." app seems to have the AirTag in a non-updating state.
How can I force it to update?

I have tried quitting the "Find my ..." app, and rebooting my MacBook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to have been resolved (for now, at least) when updating to macOS Monterey 12.3.1.